# How to display Altered value in ExtJS grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid in which I am showing data which is coming from backend. Data format is like

```
DESC:"H1",
DISP:"",
FID:474747,
VALUE : 0,
R:""
```

In this `R` value is not coming therefore I am setting `R` value from my code.

```
var record = gridEl.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++)
    record[i].set("R", RDetail); // RDetail is some value.
```

By doing this I am able to add `R` data into grid store as well as In debugger When I check It is displaying in UI. But when I close and refresh the grid `R` value is not displaying in UI.

I also have tried these

```
store.reload();
store.commitChange();
grid.reconfigure(store);
```

But displaying have some issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use renderer function for column to which parameter 'R' is assigned as  dataIndex. This function will be called for each record in store so you can write your logic to show alternate value for blank R here. This will only show changed value on UI without changing it in actual store record.

Check this example
http://extjs.eu/ext-grid-renderer-danger/

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two other ways to do this.

1. In the model definition, when you define the R column, you can add a "convert" function to populate that value when the data is loaded from the backend.
   http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert
2. In the grid column definition, you can add a renderer function to calculare that value.
   http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer